# Cant run some perl scripts from Textmate (Can't locate in @INC error)

Tags: perl, textmate

I primarily use Textmate for perl hacking on OSX Snow Leopard. It was all fine till some days ago when I installed Macports (I've heard a rumor that macports installs some version of perl in /opt/local). Now, for any new package that I install from CPAN, and try to use if from Textmate, it gives me an error like this when I hit Cmd+R to run it (I had installed HTML::TreeBuilder from CPAN moments before):

```
Can't locate HTML/TreeBuilder.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Bundles/Perl.tmbundle/Support /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/Updates/5.10.0 /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /Network/Library/Perl/5.10.0 /Network/Library/Perl /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0/darwin-thread-multi-2level /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.10.0 .) at /workspace/PerlScripts/test.pl line 2.
```

However it runs just fine when I run it from command line. If you will notice, textmate is using Perl version 5.10.0. When I run a "Perl -v" from command line, it shows me the version as 5.12.3 (see a copy paste from terminal below)

```
This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 3 (v5.12.3) built for darwin-multi-2level
```

The small perl code that I used is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl <br/>
use HTML::TreeBuilder; <br/>
print $HTML::TreeBuilder::VERSION."\n";<br/>
print "$INC{'HTML/TreeBuilder.pm'}\n";<br>
```

Then I ran "which perl" from command line and it returned this:

```
/opt/local/bin/perl
```

then I ran "print system("which perl");" from Textmate and it returned

```
/usr/bin/perl
```

Now I clearly have two versions of perl sitting in my system. 5.10.0 that Textmate is trying to refer to and which cannot see my CPAN installs. And 5.12.3 that looks to be the default version of perl when I run it from command line and the one which my CPAN installs to. I tried to replace this:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
```

with this (had read on google that this will force the system default perl to be picked up in textmate):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

No dice yet. Textmate still gives me the same error as I mentioned at the start of the question. So, is there a way to get it to work with Textmate? And is there a way to make textmate point to version 5.12.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the relevant environment variables for OS X. At the moment you probably have them set just for your shell. These will probably be PATH and PERL5LIB.

```
mkdir ~/.MacOSX
touch ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
defaults write ~/.MacOSX/environment VARIABLE_NAME VARIABLE_VALUE
```

You'll need to log out and back in again to activate it.

Comment: thanks for response Quentin. I ran an "echo $PATH" on command line and what ever paths it gave me, I put them in the environment.plist. Then I ran "echo $PERL5LIB" on command line and it returned nothing. Meaning it was not set in shell either. Please note that I am able to run perl scripts from shell, only running from textmate gives troubles. Anyways, I entered the following value for PERL5LIB in environment.plist "/opt/local/bin/perl". Then I closed and exited from textmate and relaunched. Still the error is the same. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You will need to set the Perl library path too. That is what defines `@INC`.

Comment: Is the PERL5LIB library path "/opt/local/bin/perl" incorrect? I get that path for "which perl" via command line.

Comment: That's the path to the perl executable. You want something like `/Users/quentin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.2/lib/site_perl/5.14.2/darwin-2level:/Users/quentin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.2/lib/site_perl/5.14.2:/Users/quentin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.2/lib/5.14.2/darwin-2level:/Users/quentin/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.14.2/lib/5.14.2`

Comment: Appreciate your patient replies, Quentin. Would you please tell me how to set the library path for perl on osx? I ran "Perl -V" on my terminal. It gave me this for <code>@INC</code> : <code>@INC</code>:
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl
    /opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl

Comment: Run `env | grep -i perl`. If you need to set it, then it should be obvious which one of those it is.

Comment: running "env | grep -i perl" returns nothing.

Comment: Possibly you are using entirely default paths then

Comment: Woohoo. Thanks a ton Quentin. Your suggestion of adding paths to PERL5LIB inside envoronment.plist solved the issue (as I mentioned before, I picked up the the paths by running "Perl -V" and placed them inside the plist, each path being separated by :). Then I restarted my computer. This solved the issue. You had told me to "log out and back in again" but I had not followed that little advice. Thanks a ton again. Am marking your response as Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that TextMate has your $PATH variables

in Textmate go to Preferences, then the Advanced  Tab.

Under Shell Variables, make sure the path to your preferred perl (and cpan) is there something like:

`/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Thanks for response chakram. I had those already there. I added ":/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/:/opt/local" but still textmate gives me the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Your inc path can be gotten from:

```
perl -e 'print @INC,"\n"'
```

Or from perl -V.

It is higly probable that you installed HTML::Treebuilder in a version dependent path component, so 5.12 can findit, whereas 5.10 does not.

If this is the case, you may either install the relevant modules with 5.10 OR try some tricks with lib.pm:

```
use lib qw(/usr/perl/site_perl/5.12);
```

This kind of things are best left to your package manager though, and I do not advise you do this at home unless you are totally sure of what you are doing, as you might introduce subtle bugs due to version incompatibilities (or it could just blow up, but that's easier) .

Comment: thanks ALF for response. I already ran "perl -V" and got a set of paths for INC. What I want to know is to how to make my Textmate "look" at these paths. I set this as value for PERL5LIB in envoronment.plist but the issue of Textmate giving error still remains "/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level:/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3:/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level:/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12.3:/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3/darwin-multi-2level:/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.3:/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl:/opt/local/lib/perl5/vendor_perl

Comment: Well, it is looking at your 5.12 path (from what you just wrote). Using #!/opt/local/bin/per as 1st line should totally solve *that* issue.

Comment: Thanks ALF. I had tried it before. It did not make any difference.

Comment: if someone downvoted the answer, then please write the reason for it. Otherwise, the downvote is counter productive.

Comment: So where is HTML/Treebuilder.pm sitting?

Comment: its sitting here:/opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/HTML/TreeBuilder.pm But as I mentioned before, the problem got resolved by setting PERL5LIB to all the paths seen by INC.